# Why IN operator return distinct selection when passing duplicate value (value1 , value1 ....)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008

Why does the `IN` operator return distinct values when selecting duplicate values?

Table `@temp`

```
x |      1     |       2     |      3
--+------------+-------------+------------
1 |   first 1  |    first 2  |    first 3
2 |   Second 1 |    second 2 |    second 3
```

When I execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM @temp WHERE x IN (1,1)
```

it will return

```
x |      1     |       2     |      3
--+------------+-------------+------------
1 |   first 1  |    first 2  |    first 3
```

How can I make it so it returns this instead:

```
x |      1     |       2     |      3
--+------------+-------------+------------
1 |   first 1  |    first 2  |    first 3
1 |   first 1  |    first 2  |    first 3
```

What is the alternative of `IN` in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return duplicates, then you need to phrase the query as a `join`.  The `in` is simply testing a condition on each row.  Whether the condition is met once or twice doesn't matter -- the row either stays in or gets filtered out.

```
with xes as (
      select 1 as x union all
      select 1 as x
     )
SELECT *
FROM @temp t join
     xes
     on t.x = xes.x;
```

EDIT:

If you have a subquery, then it is even simpler:

```
select *
from @temp t join
     (<subquery>) s
     on t.x = s.x
```

This would be a "normal" use of a `join`.

Comment: Could you also use a `CROSS JOIN` ?

Comment: what if you have something like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (select x from another_table)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO . . . You could use a `cross join` and then have a `where` clause that does the filtering.  I think that is bad style, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was just curious. Thanks for the explanation!